# Any good reason for the existance of helper variable template?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

**° Preamble**

- This question is particularly related to the helper variable templates defined by/in the *STL* for all the types deriving from `std::integral_constant`.

**° Context**

- I am in the process of writing a compile-time only library which aims to provide the most possible features of the *STL* *(until C++17 for now)*, by using the least possible features of the language after *C++11*.
- That is, everything that can be done using *C++11* features only, are implemented using *C++11*. For things that cannot be implemented like that, the library will have to provide other options...

*Side Note*

- The purpose is to minimize the needed modifications to the code, produced using the library, when this code has to be compiled with compilers having a reduced set of language features. Ie: Compilers of the *'embedded world'* does often not provide everything one would them to be able to do.

**° Chronology**

- *C++11* standard library came up with `std::integral_constant`.
- This *'helper class'* was already defining the cast operator for `value_type`.
- *C++14* added the invoke operator to it, and this *'new'* language feature *'variable template'*.
- *C++17* added `std::bool_constant` though `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` were
   already defined from *C++11* as `std::integral_constant<bool,` *`true`* and *`false`* `>` respectively.
- *C++17* also added `inline` variable template... There, *suddenly*, all the types deriving from `std::integral_constant` were all defining a *'helper'* variable template.

*Note*

- I perfectly understand what is the purpose of an `inline` variable template.
- The **question** here is **about the usefulness of** the *'**helpers**'* defined for the types deriving from `std::integral_constant`.

**° A Bit Food**

Now, consider the following code examples:

```
/* Test template using std::integral_constant<bool, false>
 */
template<typename...>
using AlwaysFalse = std::false_type;

/* Example #1
 */
template<typename T>
struct AssertAlwaysFalse {
    static_assert(
        AlwaysFalse<T>{},
        "Instatiation and bool cast operator replaces variable template."
    );
    using Type = T;
};

using AlwaysFalseType = typename AssertAlwaysFalse<int>::Type;

/* Example #2
 */
constexpr auto alwaysFalseAuto = AlwaysFalse<int>{};
constexpr bool alwaysFalseBool = AlwaysFalse<int>{};

/* Example #3
 */
template<bool AlwaysF>
struct AlwaysFalseArg { static constexpr bool Result = AlwaysF; };

constexpr bool alwaysFalseArg = AlwaysFalseArg<AlwaysFalse<int>{}>::Result;
```

The above examples show that instantiating an `std::integral_constant`, where a **value** is expected, has the exact same effect one would obtain by using a *'helper'* variable template.

- This is perfectly natural. `std::integral_constant` defines the cast operator for `value_type`. This behavior is **purely** *C++11*, and was available way before `inline` variable template.

**° Still Stands The Question**

- Is there only **one** good reason for having defined these *'helper'* variable templates for **all** the types deriving from `std::integral_constant` ***???***

---

**° In Other Words**

After the comment of @NicolBolas about:

> *"Why instantiating some object **only to convert it into a compile-time value** ?"*

I realized that the main point behind the question was maybe not enough clear. *So I will put it like that:*

- If you only had at disposal the features provided with *C++11*, ***How would you implement** 'something' **to provide this compile-time value ?***

Comment: "*This is perfectly natural.*" It's a type. You want a value of a *different* type. Why is it "natural" that you should instantiate some object only to convert it into a compile-time value? Doesn't it make a lot more sense to just *get a compile-time value*? Why do you need those `{}` there?

Comment: @NicolBolas the `{}` will create a _temporary_ for the compiler to use/call the `value_type` cast operator... #1 As long as the temporary is not assigned, it will _'disappear'_ as fast as it came... #2 The `value_type` cast operator is defined `constexpr` _(and `inline` from C++17)_, and it returns the `static constexpr value_type` **value**... All this is **purely** _"get a compile-time value"_... _No ?!_

Comment: What is going on with the formatting?  `>` is a quote, what are you quoting?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Ok, ok. I didn't know/thought that this _'rule'_ was strict to that point... I used this formatting also like some kind of a parenthesis within the text. _But if it prevents people from focusing on the question, or from 'simply' reading the post until the end..._ You're right. That's no good for the question to find its answer. I gave it a second try. Tell me if that's better.

Comment: @Tenphase: I know how it works. I'm questioning why you consider this convoluted scheme of instantiating a temporary object of some type and converting it to some other type to be a natural way to get a value compared to just... using a variable. Isn't the variable the obvious, "natural" way to store a value?

Comment: @Tenphase: Also, why does your text have so many random line breaks in it. Browsers use word-wrapping; we don't need you to wrap for us. Just let your paragraphs be paragraphs, formatted for our screens.

Comment: @Tenphase: "*How would you implement 'something' to provide this compile-time value ?*" Given the limitations of C++11, what was done in the standard library seems to be an adequate-if-inelegant solution. That is, it's as good as the language can make it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Indeed... Said this way, that's perfectly obvious. But if you do not have a compiler providing such a _variable_, what can you do then ?! That's roughly the question behind the question...

Answer (score 1):

The main benefits are compilation speed, consistency, and convenience, primarily.  I'm going to take a look at a few things here.  I'll try to address both what the features are used for, and how one would implement them with only C++11 features.  If you only care about the implementation ideas, skip to the bottom.

---

#### `integral_constant` itself:

First, we have the central object here, `std::integral_constant`.  It defines a compile-time static constant, accessed as `std::integral_constant<T, V>::value`, and looks something like this<sup>taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)</sup>.

```
template<class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
    static constexpr T value = v;
    using value_type = T;
    using type = integral_constant; // using injected-class-name
    constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept { return value; }
    constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept { return value; } // since c++14
};
```

Now, the first thing to note is that `integral_constant` stores the constant's value within itself, as a compile-time constant.  You can access it without instantiating an instance; furthermore, instantiating the `integral_constant` will typically just result in an object being created and immediately converted to the constant, doing extra work for zero benefit; it's usually better to just use `integral_constant::value` directly instead.

```
constexpr bool TraitResult = integral_constant<bool, SomeConstexprTest(param)>::value;
```

---

#### SFINAE, Traits, and `bool_constant`:

The most common use case for `integral_constant`, by *far*, is as a compile-time boolean trait, likely used for SFINAE or introspection.  The vast majority of `<type_traits>` consists of `integral_constant<bool>`s, with values determined according to the trait's logic, for use as yes-or-no tests.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<  std::is_same<SomeType, T>::value>::type
someFunc(T&& t);

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<SomeType, T>::value>::type
someFunc(T&& t);
```

C++17 supplies `bool_constant` with this usage in mind, as a cleaner way to create boolean constants.  It allows for cleaner code by simplifying the creation of custom traits:

```
namespace detail {
    // These lines are clean.
    template<typename...> struct are_unique_helper;
    template<typename T>  struct are_unique_helper<T> : std::true_type {};

    // This... less so.
    template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
    struct are_unique_helper<T, U, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        !std::is_same<T, U> &&
        are_unique_helper<T, Ts...>::value
    > {};
}

// With integral_constant<bool>.
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct are_unique : std::integral_constant<bool, detail::are_unique_helper<T, Ts...>::value && are_unique<Ts...>::value> {};

// With bool_constant.
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct are_unique : std::bool_constant<detail::are_unique_helper<T, Ts...>::value && are_unique<Ts...>::value> {};
```

The name `bool_constant` conveys the same information as `integral_constant<bool>` with less wasted space or one less line, depending on coding style, and has the additional advantange of clearer conveyance thanks to emphasising the `bool` part.  It's not strictly necessary, and can be easily supplied manually if your compiler doesn't support it, but it does provide a few benefits.

---

#### `true_type` and `false_type`:

These two provide specific constants for `true` and `false`; this is definitely useful, but many traits determine `v` with boolean logic.  (See, e.g., `std::is_same` or `are_unique` above.)  They're neither a be-all nor an end-all, though they can serve useful purposes such as base values for traits (as above, or as in `std::is_same`), or matching traits for overloading or SFINAE.

```
constexpr std::string_view isIntInner( std::true_type) { return "yes"; }
constexpr std::string_view isIntInner(std::false_type) { return " no"; }

template<typename T>
constexpr std::string_view isInt(T&&) {
    return isIntInner(std::is_same<int, T>{});
}
```

---

#### Helpers: Type aliases & variable templates:

To explain the reason for the variable templates, we also want to look at them alongside the helper aliases defined in C++14.

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;

template< class T, class U >
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;
```

These mainly exist as a form of convenience, really; they're a bit faster to type, a bit cleaner to read, and require a bit less finger gymnastics.  The type aliases were provided first, and the helper variables are mainly there for consistency with them.

---

#### How to implement these:

You mentioned that you're aiming to implement everything using C++11 features primarily.  This will allow you to provide most of the above:

- `integral_constant`: Requires only C++11 or earlier features.  (`constexpr` and `noexcept`.)
- `bool_constant`: Introduced in C++17, but requires only C++11 features.  (Alias template.)
- `true_type` and `false_type`: Same as `integral_constant`.
- Introspective logic type traits: Same as `integral_constant`.
- Helper `_t` aliases: Introduced in C++14, but requires only C++11 features.  (Alias template.)
- Helper `_v` variables: Requires C++14 features.  (Variable template.)

It wouldn't actually be too hard to provide helper aliases and `bool_constant` for compilers which don't support it, as long as `using` templates is supported.  Possibly by, e.g., providing them within your library's namespace, in a header which is only loaded on implementations that don't include the aliases, and/or which the library's consumer can enable or disable as necessary during compilation.

While it would take a lot of work to implement variable templates, however, you do have another, more C++11-compliant option: helper functions.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
inline constexpr bool is_same_v() noexcept {
    return std::is_same<T, U>::value;
}
```

Providing functions of this sort will result in code nearly as clean as the helper variable templates, which can be cleanly switched over to the official variable templates for compilers which provide them.  There are a few slight differences between helper functions and helper variables, though I'm not sure if there are any use cases that would actually care about them, and the library would ideally only provide helper functions for compilers which don't themselves provide the `_v` variables.

Comment: Thanks for the details _(and for your time)_. I would say that you roughly summarized what my conclusion was _(which led me to ask this question to see if there might have other options)_. In fact, I am re-implementing most of the types of `&lt;type_traits&gt;` using a different naming convention. Hence, there will have an abstraction layer above the ones of the _STL_ for which the implementation is impossible _(or will come later on)_. I didn't think about a helper function _(I would have made it `inline` `noexcept`)_. But the `()` would be an obstacle to port the code...

Comment: BTW, the `_v` helper variable templates have only been added to the _STL_ since _C++17_... I would say _(I think)_ that they were added _only_ at that time, because _C++17_ added `inline` variable templates. This allows the compiler not to generate a symbol _(which would not have had been obvious with C++14)_.

Comment: You're quite welcome, @Tenphase.  Most of the features definitely could exist as early as C++11, and are mainly the benefit of hindsight saying, "We should've done this from the start."  I hadn't thought about the `_v` helpers possibly needing `inline` variable templates specifically, though, that's a very good point.  You could potentially avoid the `()` breaking code by providing the `_v`s as macros that expand to differently-named functions (and are only meant to be available if the actual `_v` variables don't exist in a given implementation), but that could get very messy very quickly.

Comment: (And, as a note, [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) implies `inline` in this use case, and `noexcept()` returns true for constant expressions.  Thus, `inline` isn't necessary in the function declaration, and `noexcept` is useful but non-essential; in this specific case, we can expect that there should only be the possibility of an exception being thrown if something is seriously wrong with the compiler's implementation of `integral_constant`.  They're perfectly fine as a style choice, though, and the added clarity can be beneficial.)

Comment: Thank you very much. – As long as their usage is not absolutely mandatory, I prefer not to use macros inside the code _(especially to 'select' an identifier)_. They are good for what they are inside headers _(language &amp; compiler versions &amp; options, build options, etc...)_. Hence, I've decided not to use variable templates at all within the library, and to provide them as a build option for the code using the library. _(meaning that the code using variable temples, with this option enabled, with 'only' be C++14 compatible)_ – This leaves the freedom to choose to the user...

Comment: That sounds like a good way to handle it, @Tenphase.  Simple, clean, and fully up to the user & their environment. 